# What is the mathematical term that can differentiate two same vectors?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, education

Say i have two vectors  A and B. 
Mathematically they are same if they have same magnitude and direction.

So, say if someone asks me to draw a "vector" of 5 magnitude with 45 degree angle with x-axis.. i can draw infinite such vectors on the graph.

My question is, what is the mathematical term, say if i want to have a special vector having fixed end points. So that if i say draw " ***_*____** " that has magnitude 5, with 45 degree, and starts from [x,y] and ends at [x2,y2] ?

Comment: the vector is uniquely determinated by magnitude and direction , you don't have infinite of them?

Comment: If i ask one to draw a vector of magnitude 5 with 30 degree angle... you can make infinite number of such vectors on a graph paper. I answered my own question here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441807/a-vector-should-more-be-thought-an-identity-of-an-entity-in-space-rathar-than-ma?rq=1

Comment: Not if the vector starts form the origin.

Comment: If you draw infinitely many such vectors on a piece of graph paper you will have infinitely many representations of the same vector. As Amire Bendjeddou comments I am assuming all of your drawn vectors start from the origin.

Comment: I would argue that what you are drawing are not vectors but line segments in an affine space.

Comment: @Amire : It's not mandatory for a vector to start from origin.

Comment: @zuggg : But line segments are only and only "magnitudes" . They are not even having specific directions.

Comment: @VishwasGagrani I think what you are looking for is called position vector : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_(vector). Your reference origin is $[x,y]$

Comment: I think it's a directed line segment. See here: http://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/107/vectors/vect.htm or here: http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~jmckinno/Chapter1/Lecture1c.pdf

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou the OP means the starting point is not fixed.

Comment: @gt6989b In his question he is looking for the definition of a vector ( with given magnitude and direction) wich starts form a given point [x,y] , to me it seems like the definition of position vector with [x,y] beeing the reference origin is in accordance with the definition he is looking for. If i'm wrong  i would like to know why , since this is a question i'm interested too now.

Comment: @Amire : I think, how it is defined there, it's possible to draw more than one "position vectors" on a graph paper. Because starting point is not fixed. So, it cannot me uniquely identified.

Comment: I didn't know about this question and asked a similar one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1604668/301964

Comment: In physics, you could actually draw multiple vectors with the same direction, magnitude *and* origin. For instance, a point charge body may experience two vectorially equal forces from two other charged bodies.

Comment: For instance, two forces on a point charge body may be made equal by placing two other bodies of opposite charge at the same distance but on opposite sides of it.

Answer (score 3):

A vector, by definition, is only a magnitude and a direction. If someone asks you to draw a given vector on paper, you can draw an infinite number of them, but they are just instances of the same vector.

By analogy, suppose someone asked you to write the number $6$. No matter where you write it on the paper, it is still a $6$.

I believe the term you're looking for is a **directed line segment**, which is distinct from a vector. A directed line segment can be defined in one of two ways:

parametric equations:
$$\begin{align}
x(t)&= at+b \\
y(t)&= ct+d \\
t_1&\le{t}\le{t_2}
\end{align}$$

or basic Euclidean coordinate functions:
$$y=mx+b,x_1\le{x}\le{x_2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I have sometimes heard this called a *bound vector* (as opposed to a *free vector*). But most people in the comments are right - this isn't a standard term, and terms like this are normally used in very specific, technical uses or as teaching aids. In most standard mathematics, vectors don't have start- and end-points - that is, regardless of where you draw it, if it has the same magnitude and direction, it's the same vector. All vectors are free.

Comment: Do you have a link or a reference to any examples of this term being used?

Comment: No, I've only ever heard it used by lecturers to undergraduates (and even then it wasn't used in courses I took, only courses I've helped to teach).