# Is there a relation name that only applies to equal vectors if they also have the same origin?

Tags: vector-spaces, equivalence-relations

Vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are equal if they have the same magnitude and direction. Is there a mathematical relation defined to apply to them only if they also have the same origin?

Actually, I would like to have concepts to distinguish between these three cases:

(I) $\vec{A}$ is equal to $\vec{B}$ but with different origin,

(II) $\vec{A}$ is equal to $\vec{B}$ with the same origin,

(III) $\vec{A}$ is the same entity as $\vec{B}$.

As a physical example, the difference between (II) and (III) could be

(II - example) $\vec{F}_1$ and $\vec{F}_2$ are two forces applied on the same point,

(III - example) $\vec{F}_1$ and $\vec{F}_2$ are actually a single force, the same entity.

Comment: Ordinarily, vectors don't have an origin; they only have magnitude and direction.

Comment: @BrianTung: Maybe the OP works in an affine space? The space of Newtonian physics is affine, for instance, and this seems to be the OP's context (he mentions forces).

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, I'm a physicist who wants to know if Mathematics already has the concepts I need. If Mathematics lack the concepts to distinguish between those cases, that's OK, I just say that to my students and say that those distinctions are not made in Mathematics, only in Physics.

Comment: Vectors kind of represent *directions*. If you want to include information on the *origin*, then you might be rather interested in *couple of points* (origin, end).

Comment: @LeonardoCastro Two vectors (in Euclidean space, say) are the same if they have the same magnitude and direction. So your conditions I, II, and III all denote the same vector. In applications we may *choose a representative* of the vector based at some point. But it's still the same vector. In other words a vector is the entire equivalence class of directed arrows having the same length and direction. In a sense, a given vector is already based at every point; or more accurately a given vector has a representative based at every point.

Comment: (+1) @LeonardoCastro: The following terms are probably not standard, but if you're speaking of vectors in the plane or in space, it would be reasonable to say: (I) _Parallel_, (II) _Mathematically equal_, (III) _Physically equal_. (Commenting instead  answering because there are substantial nuances implicit in the question, but attempting to address them completely seems beside the point for your purposes.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I like your definitions and think that they could become standard. I'm in doubt about the _physically equal_ definition, because two forces applied on the same point might have same magnitude and direction but still not be the same force. For instance, you can apply, with your hands, a force with same magnitude and direction as gravitational force on the center of mass of a body, but the force you apply isn't still the _same entity_ as the gravitational force; your force actually doubles the effect of gravity.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Anyway, `being the same entity` might be another question beyond equality and equivalence.

Comment: @Leonardo: I'd understood (III) to mean "one and the same force". That is, I'd consider gravity and the force of one's hand in your example to be "mathematically equal" or "type (II)". :) (Anyway, maybe "physically identical" would be better for (III)?) Separately, I suspect universal names don't exist because in practice much of the time one can be a bit sloppy; there's no widespread need to be exacting to this level of distinction....

Comment: @AndreasT Come to think of it, the _couple-of-points_ approach wouldn't work for forces applied on points, since forces and positions are different physical quantities, measured in different unities. It only works for _displacement vectors_.

Comment: I think _forces_ are not really represented by vectors, but rather by _vectors placed on positions_.

Comment: All these comments helped me reach the conclusion that there are no standard concepts for the distinctions I presented and that most physical quantities represented vectorially are not completely defined by vectors. I think I should accept an answer if there was any presented as an actual answer instead of as a comment.